# Есть ли ошибки в постановке знаков препинания в данном предложении?

Tags: запятые, спп, сложное-предложение, обороты-с-как

Свою любовь Лермонтов называет "странной", потому что видит все недостатки России как государства, но продолжает любить её всем сердцем.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Запятые в предложении расставлены правильно.
*Свою любовь Лермонтов называет "странной",*(1) *потому что видит все недостатки России*(2) *как государства,*(3) *но продолжает любить её всем сердцем.*

**(1)** "Придаточные предложения, присоединяемые союзом «потому(,) что», выделяются (или отделяются) запятыми".
*Эта мысль не показалась мне странной, **потому что** формальное измерение времени, искусственно оторванного от пространства...* (В. П. Катаев. Святой колодец).

**(2)** "Если союз «как» имеет значение ‘в качестве’, то присоединяемый им оборот не обособляется..."
*Бывало, что на кону даже стоял вопрос о самом существовании **России как государства**, народа, цивилизации* (В. Матвиенко).

**(3)** Внутри предложения перед союзом «но» всегда ставится запятая (в данном случае при противопоставлении однородных сказуемых: *видит, но продолжает любить*).
*...плачет по ночам, **но** продолжает любить* (Д. Каралис).

[потому(,) что](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_611) (союз)
[Запятая перед союзом КАК](https://pedsovet.org/article/zapyataya-pered-soyuzom-kak#:%7E:text=%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%8F%20%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%20%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%8E%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%BC%20%D0%9A%D0%90%D0%9A%20%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F,%D0%9E%D0%BD%20%D1%83%D0%BF%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%BC%2C%20%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA%20%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BB.)
[Запятая перед «но»](https://pishugramotno.ru/punktuacia/zapyataya-pered-no-stavitsya-ili-net)